# Java JSONArray Object Returns HTML Format?

Tags: java, json, spring, controller

I am using Java Spring and I am trying to return a JSON object in json format. However my controller below returns a funny HTML format for JSON data, see below.
I want the controller to return the data as JSON formatted data not XML...

Any Ideas?
Thanks,
Pete

Data Returned:

```
    <JSONArray><item><date><date>11</date><hours>15</hours><seconds>52</seconds> 
   <month>11</month><nanos>0</nanos><timezoneOffset>300</timezoneOffset> 
   <year>117</year><minutes>32</minutes><time>1513024372000</time><day>1</day> 
   </date><exception></exception><level>DEBUG</level> 
   <logger>com.foo.bar.webapp.controller.ReconcileController</logger><id>91</id> 
   <message>filter was empty</message></item><item><date><date>11</date> 
   <hours>15</hours><seconds>52</seconds><month>11</month><nanos>0</nanos> 
   <timezoneOffset>300</timezoneOffset><year>117</year><minutes>32</minutes> 
   <time>1513024372000</time><day>1</day></date><exception></exception> 
   <level>DEBUG</level><logger>com.foo.bar.webapp.controller.ReconcileController
   </logger><id>92</id><message>returning labels as string</message> 
   </item><item><date><date>11</date><hours>15</hours><seconds>52</seconds> 
   <month>11</month><nanos>0</nanos><timezoneOffset>300</timezoneOffset> 
   <year>117</year><minutes>32</minutes><time>1513024372000</time><day>1</day> 
   </date><exception></exception><level>DEBUG</level> 
   <logger>com.foo.bar.webapp.controller.ReconcileController...
```

Controller Method :

```
@RequestMapping("/data*")
@Produces("application/json")
@ResponseBody
public JSONArray getData() {

    List<LogEntry> logs = logEntryManager.getLogsByDate( new Date() );

    JsonConfig config = new JsonConfig();
    config.addIgnoreFieldAnnotation(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore.class);

    Log.trace("Get LogEntry Data Only");
    JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject( logs, config );

    return jsonArray;
}
```

Comment: Please post your pom.xml (if its a maven project) or included libraries in the project ?

Comment: Also if you set `Accept` header to `application/json' at rest client (like Postman), do you get desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "data", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
public @ResponseBody JSONArray getData() {

    List<LogEntry> logs = logEntryManager.getLogsByDate( new Date() );

    JsonConfig config = new JsonConfig();
    config.addIgnoreFieldAnnotation(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore.class);

    Log.trace("Get LogEntry Data Only");
    JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject( logs, config );

    return jsonArray;
}
```

ignore your `@Produces` annotation

try this.

Comment: This did not work :( Still returns the XML style data.

Comment: This worked.  I changed the RequestMethod to GET and it Worked!